# Updating Current map_start_time and map_end_time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, time-series, temporal-controller

I'm experimenting with the temporal controller in QGIS in map layouts

I want to current time frame (see below)

[image]

To update the map_start_time and map_end_time in the variable section in the layout menu (see below)

[image]

Is there any way to "refresh" the map_start_time and map_end_time from the current layout?

Thanks in advance.